# How to get the index of selected, click icon in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a set of JSON data,

**NEED IS** **:**

1) I took all the data from JSON using ng-repeat

2) I have 3 buttons, if I click any one of the button all 3 json value is gone.

3) I want to pass only the clicked button's info value in ng-click as an argument.

4) How to get which button has been clicked and how to pass {{task.info}} value to the particular content.

5) If I select id="2", I want to pass only that second id values in a ng-click function call (i.e ng-click="getDetails(task.info)").

```js
var tasks = [{
id : 1,
name : 'jhonny',
point : 25,
info:'<div><ul>
          <li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>',
},
{
id : 2,
name : 'mani',
point : 25,
info:'<div><ul>
          <li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>',
},
{
id : 1,
name : 'kumar',
point : 65
info:'<div><ul>
          <li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>',
},
```

Here, I want to pass the **info** value in ng-click function. But how can I get to know which info has been clicked.

```html
<li ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
  <button ng-click="testTask(task.name)"></button>
</li>
```

Comment: Not sure if you had made a mistake in your posted code as the ids are not unique. Do you want to index of the clicked item, or the `id` of it? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

Check out a working example here: 
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/waKLtfdQyGaY8N5Q

You can pass the entire task object in, then you'll have name and info available to your function:

```
<li ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
  <button ng-click="testTask(task)">{{task.name}}</button>
</li>
```

Then in `testTask` function, you can access `task.name` and `task.info` for the clicked item.

**html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      <p>Start editing and see your changes reflected here!</p>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
          <button ng-click="testTask(task)">{{task.name}}</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Plunker';
  $scope.tasks = [
    {
    id : 1,
    name : 'jhonny',
    point : 25,
    info:`<div><ul>
              <li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>`
    },
    {
    id : 2,
    name : 'mani',
    point : 25,
    info:`<div><ul>
              <li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>`
    },
    {
    id : 1,
    name : 'kumar',
    point : 65,
    info: `<div><ul>
              <li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>`
    }
  ];
  $scope.testTask = function(task) {
    console.log(task);
    window.alert(task.id + ' ' + task.name);
  }
});
```

Comment: If it is 100 data, how can I check which button has clicked. For example If i click id="3", I want to show only that value in a popup. But for me all json values are going.

Comment: @sathishkumar The `task` object passed in would be the current one clicked. If you clicked on the `id="3"`, the task object with the `id="3"` would be the one being used in `testTask(task)`.

Comment: @Jimenemex if I print the task value in console, all json files are showing not only one. Am I need to get index value. But here id is unique.

Comment: @sathishkumar I've updated the answer and provided a working solution, hopefully it is clear. You don't need the index of the clicked item, you get a reference to the individual record passed into the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$index` variable, from the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) doc:

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given
>   loop variable is set to the current collection item, and **$index** is set
>   to the item index or key.

so you can do:

```
<li ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
  <button ng-click="testTask($index, task.name)"></button>
</li>
```

**Demo**:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.tasks = [{
id : 1,
name : 'jhonny',
point : 25,
info:'<div><ul><li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li><li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li><li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li></ul></div>'
},
{
id : 2,
name : 'mani',
point : 25,
info:'<div><ul><li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li><li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li><li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li></ul></div>'
},
{
id : 1,
name : 'kumar',
point : 65,
info:'<div><ul><li><a href="#tab-1"> Tab 1 </a></li><li><a href="#tab-2"> Tab 2 </a></li><li><a href="#tab-3"> Tab3 </a></li></ul></div>',
}];

  $scope.testTask = (index, name) => {
     console.log('index: ', index);
     console.log('name: ', name); 
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
     <button ng-click="testTask($index, task.name)">{{task.name}}</button>
   </li>
 </div>

</div>
```